# Error while splitting string in java : error: array required, but String found

Tags: java, split

I have a String as follows :

```
String abc = "abc......|pqr.....";
```

I am splitting the string using split method in Java as follows:

```
String[] splt = abc.split("\\|");   
String a = splt[0]; >> Expecting val = abc......
String b = splt[0]; >> Expecting val = pqr.....
```

But I am getting error as follows:

```
 error: array required, but String found
```

Comment: `String[] splt = abc.split("\\|");`...

Comment: `String b = splt[0]` => `String b = splt[1]`, I'd imagine.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @OP I can't reproduce your problem. Please update your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and full error message.

Comment: @Santhucool Can you please provide entire method where you call split? It works fine for me.

Comment: I got that buddy, Reimus was spot on thanks!!

Comment: So can we expect you to update your question with proper SSCCE in near future or should we vote to close this question since as it stays now, its code doesn't let us reproduce problem you described?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String[] splt = Pattern.compile("\\|").split(abc)
```

or

```
String[] splt = abc.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Then iterate array inside for loop

```
for (String string : splt) {

        System.out.println(string);

    }
```